# Sublime Text 2 freezing when I type ></

Tags: macos, crash, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have been using Sublime Text 2 on my MacBook Air OSX 10.9.5 Mavericks for a good 2 years now.

The past week, it tends to freeze when I type `></`.  In particular, I am usually typing `<script src="someurl.js"></` when it happens (Although it has happened in a few other situations too).  It is intermittent and not 100% predictable.  The application freezes, the spinning beach ball of death appears, and the Force Quit Applications menu shows that it is "not responding".  I must force quit the application.  Then I'll re-open the application and try to type the same thing and it will freeze again.  Usually this repeats 4 times or so and then it decides to work again.

It could possibly be specific to HTML documents.  But not specific to the syntax highlighter.

Here is a glance at top processes on my computer.  It says 3 are stuck, but I can't find the other two:

[image]

I am not willing to switch to a different text editor, but I am willing to upgrade to Sublime Text 3 if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: How strange, maybe an extra installed plugin/extension is messing with the editor while you type that text?

Comment: It's crashing pretty consistently now, so I have a good opportunity to troubleshoot.  I have just disabled all packages listed by Package Control, including Package Control itself, and I still get the same crash.

Comment: Any troubleshooting ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are better off asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can't replicate on ST3. I am going to suggest most of the people who can help you are running ST3 now so I would suggest trying the upgrade and then at least we can troubleshoot with you.

Comment: Is there a recommended migration process for all my preferences, key bindings, packages, etc?

Comment: Try disabling auto close HTML tags option. Add this line to your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file: `"auto_close_tags": false` and see if it helps.
Also I don't remember the last time I closed a HTML tag myself. Try using Emmet. In your case write `script:src` and press `Tab`

Comment: @Taylan That's a good idea.  I've moved to Sublime Text 3 by now, so I can't test out your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Sublime Text 3 solved the problem.

This isn't a fully satisfactory answer, since it doesn't say how to fix the issue in Sublime Text 2, but it is the only known answer at this point.